# What is the controller used and what are other components in the system pictured below

Tags: control-theory

[IMAGE discussed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNAXc.png)

I have tried everything to identify the type of PID controller used but I think I'm missing something. The denominator of (s+10) really throws me off. Otherwise it would be standard system from below. The PID I know is standart Kc+Kds+Ki/s and half the transfer function fits it except for the abovementioned denominator

[Image example of system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5gDv.png)

**The extensive question is:** i.e. which actions and/or other components
are present in this controller?

As far as I understand the controller + actuator combo comes before disturbance and after the disturbance comes the plant. Standard closed loop system. I have done a lot of searching and tried to fit in similar first/second order systems but none of them looked the same. Below is what I got as a complete transfer function of the system, albeit rearanged

$$
\frac{(d s + 10 d + 6 s + 20)(r - z)}{s (s + 10)}  = z
$$

Comment: It is difficult to give a precise answer based on the provided information but that looks like a PD controller with filtered derivative.

Comment: I agree what KBS said, about it being a PD controller with low pass on the derivative (to make it causal). One could also call is a [lead-lag compensator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93lag_compensator).

Comment: I see, I think I found it on our notes finally. It will be low pass filter then, thank you for your help @KBS and Kwin

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the [PID Controller article](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller.html#mw_8008046a-81c5-4ae0-9fd7-3834478483b3_sep_mw_88993414-f49e-4ddb-a92a-4bc5cd2fa840) here, yours should be the ideal form of the PD controller structure:

$$G_{c}(s) = K_{p} \left[1 + \tau_{d} \frac{N s}{s + N}\right]$$

where $N$ is known as the [Derivative filter coefficient](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller.html#mw_8008046a-81c5-4ae0-9fd7-3834478483b3_sep_mw_afc1053b-7027-47f7-b645-90304934fbd4).

When compared with the given controller

$$G_{c}(s) = 2 \left[1 + \frac{2 s}{s + 10}\right]$$

we know that $N = 10$, and since $\tau_{d} N = 2$, then $\tau_{d} = \frac{1}{5}$.

Sometimes, it is also expressed in this standard form as shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/proportional-integral-derivative-pid-controllers.html#bsvj1gy):

$$G_{c}(s) = K_{p} \left[1 + \frac{\tau_{d} s}{\frac{1}{N} s + 1}\right]$$

I personally prefer to write the PD controller in this form:

$$G_{c}(s) = K_{p} + K_{d} \frac{s}{\tau_{f} s + 1}$$